# AWS device farm- "Unlimited Testing" plan

Tags: aws-device-farm

I am using the free trial of 1000 MIN, In this trial I can't see Android device above Android 5.0,
Is the reason for this is because I am free in the free trial?
If I will buy the plan "Unlimited Testing" will I get an option to the devices with Android 5.0 and above?

Comment: Is this for remote testing or automated tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for remote testing only a subset of devices are available compared to automated tests.

http://awsdevicefarm.info/

This is expected currently. For more remote access options you would need to use the private offering from Device Farm.